# Copy clicked image src to other element background attribute with Vue

Tags: vue.js

Im loading images with Vue resource (ajax). How can I copy clicked image src attribute and use it in div background attribute?

Comment: Please provide some code or a jsfiddle example of what you are trying to do so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy on click element test with:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { src: ""},
    methods: {
        copySRC: function(event){
            this.src = event.target.src;
            this.copyClipboard();
        },
        copyClipboard: function() {
          this.$refs["input"].select();
          document.execCommand("copy");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
img,input {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/100"
    @click="copySRC"
    title="click to copy in the input"
  />
  <input
    v-model="src"
    ref="input"
    @click="copyClipboard"
    title="click to copy in clipboard"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/q7xcbuxd/32/

```
<div id="app">
    Click on the image:<br/>
    <img id="img" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/2885?v=3&s=96" v-on="click: copySrc">
    <div>
        {{src}}
    </div>
</div>


var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        src: ""
    },

    methods: {
        copySrc: function(img){
            this.src = img.srcElement.src;
        }
    }
});
```